# How do i select a substring from a string acording to the last "/"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a image url and would like to subtract the last string after "/" , for example from string "www.abc.com/images/photo.jpg" i would like to get the string "photo.jpg". How can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NSString` `-(NSString *)lastPathComponent;` for that.

Comment: i will in 5 minutes, when they will allow me :P

Answer (score 1):

```
    String s = "www.abc.com/images/photo.jpg";


        String[] newS = s.split("/");

        String correctS = newS[newS.length-1];
```

correctS will hold your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex for it:

(?!/)[^/]*$